# Members with the containing class type as a template argument

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm having some problems getting some code to compile that can easily be summed up with the following code:

```
template <typename _Ty>
class Foo
{
public:
    using allocator_type = typename _Ty::allocator_type;
};

template <typename _Ty, typename _Alloc = std::allocator<_Ty>>
class Bar
{
public:
    using allocator_type = _Alloc;

    Foo<Bar<_Ty, _Alloc>> foo;
};

int main(void)
{
    Foo<Bar<int>> x;
}
```

This fails to compile in Visual Studio with the following error:

```
Error   1   error C2079: 'Bar<int,std::allocator<_Ty>>::foo' uses undefined class 'Foo<Bar<int,std::allocator<_Ty>>>'   c:\users\duncan\desktop\test\test\main.cpp  17  1   Test
```

This would obviously be an issue if `Foo` had a member of type `_Ty` (for the same reason `Foo` cannot have a member of type `Foo`), but since that is not the case here, I'm a bit confused. What throws me off even more is that if I change the `foo` member of `Bar` to a pointer, the compiler error goes away. Even crazier, `Foo<Bar<_Ty, _Alloc>>` can be used as a local variable within a member function of `Bar` with no errors.

Is there anything in the standard preventing such usage, or is this a bug with the Visual Studio 2013 compiler? I don't currently have easy access to a compiler with GCC to test it out there. This pattern seems like something that would be desirable to follow.

Comment: Both g++ and clang++ reject this code.

Comment: _"I don't currently have easy access to a compiler with GCC to test it out there."_ [That's not quite true!](http://ideone.com/MDUY9d) It gives you the same error report more or less. The problem is that you try to use `Bar` where it's declaration  isn't yet complete.

Comment: I've had issues in the past with ideone not being up-to-date and have since stopped relying on it (perhaps that has changed since then... that was back in the days when C++11 wasn't fully supported yet). Anyway, thanks for the response; that makes a lot of sense.

Comment: I usually use [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/) which is more customizable than ideone (and supports both clang++ and g++) , or [godbolt](http://gcc.godbolt.org/) when I want to see the disassembly.

Comment: @T.C. I'm used to do both. Coliru is reserved for the more complicated cases. To have just a quick test, ideone usually works better for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code doesn't compile because at the time of the instantiation of template specialization `class Bar<int>` it asks for a concrete `Bar<int>` object inside the definition of `class Bar<int>`. This is not allowed because at the time the compiler sees `Foo<Bar<int>> foo;`, it knows nothing about `Bar<int>` (i.e., definition of template specialization `Bar<int>` is not complete).

What you can do about it is either pass `Bar` as a pointer. To accomplish this you'll need also to specialize `Foo` for pointers, like the example below:

```
template <typename _Ty>
class Foo
{
public:
  using allocator_type = typename _Ty::allocator_type;
};

template <typename T>
class Foo<T*>
{
public:
  using allocator_type = typename T::allocator_type;
};

template <typename _Ty, typename _Alloc = std::allocator<_Ty>>
class Bar
{
public:
  using allocator_type = _Alloc;

  Foo<Bar*> foo;
};
```

### [LIVE DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f23bc6acc66781ae)

Or force create template specialization `Bar<int>` in order for the compiler to know it beforehand:

```
template <typename _Ty>
class Foo
{
public:
  using allocator_type = typename _Ty::allocator_type;
};

template <typename _Ty, typename _Alloc = std::allocator<_Ty>>
class Bar
{
public:
  using allocator_type = _Alloc;

  Foo<Bar> foo;
};

template class Bar<int>; // force create Bar<int>
```

### [LIVE DEMO](http://ideone.com/s7Fs0w)

Also have in mind that:

- Underscore followed by a capital letter is reserved for use in STL.
- The name of `Bar` is injected in the definition of `template class Bar`. Consequently, using inside template definition `Bar<T, Alloc>` or `Bar` is the same.

Comment: *"Underscore followed by a capital letter is reserved for use in STL"* While true, I can site millions of lines of code that would cease to compile if an STL implementer went happy-go-lucky with that rule. Anyway, thanks for the concise answer, though I actually ended up going with a separate "types class" after reading πάντα ῥεῖ's answer.